# Online mockup/wireframe tool

Tags: web-apps, web-development, hosted, wireframing

I'm looking for a web-based app which I would use to create quick mockup/wireframe of a web page and share that with a client.

Main requirements are:

- Free (or cheap, less than $5 per month)
- Online based
- Can share link of mockup without asking user who needs to see it to register

Optional

- Usable on tablets or have Android app
- Can export design as PNG or JPG

Comment: For other visitors: [Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/buy/#myb) starts at 12$/m, so it seems not a valid answer here, otherwise I'd probably have suggested it.

Comment: And [Pencil](https://github.com/prikhi/pencil) is not available as a web app. Damn, no reputation to earn today ;-)

Comment: @Thomas Tell the OP to just use [Cameyo's Play feature](https://player.vimeo.com/video/140640012) with Pencil:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second is called Mockplus. It also offers a free and premium version, the free version includes quite a few features:

> - Support all platforms(iOS/Android/PC/Web)
> - Sketch and wireframe style
> - 200 components
> - 8 markup components
> - Visualized interaction design
> - 8 pre-designed interaction components
> - Various events and commands
> - Execute interaction sequentially & simultaneously
> - Interaction state
> - Masters
> - My favorites
> - Fast review
> - Scan QR code to preview app prototype on mobile
> - Auto backup
> - Batch modification
> - Page tag
> - Component remarks
> - Import & export component fragment
> - Import & export project fragment
> - Ruler and guidelines
> - Share prototypes
> - Shortcuts

This basically includes all of your requirements but if you want to export to PNG/JPG, you're going to have to buy the Pro version.

## [Mockplus](http://www.mockplus.com/) (freemium)

> If you are looking for a tool that makes you design easier and faster, you cannot go pass Mockplus.
>
> 1. Fast Interaction- Interactive design is easier than ever - The interactive design in Mockplus is fully visualized, that's
>    WYSIWYG. With a simple drag-and-drop to build interactive prototypes
>    effortlessly. A set of pre-designed components, including pop-up
>    panel, stack panel, scroll box, sliding drawer and image carousel,
>    make you create fully interactions faster and easier.
> 2. Fast Design -Prototype like a Pro with extensive pre-designed components Mockplus comes with more than 400 icons and nearly 200
>    components. Just drag these components into the workspace for a
>    combination to prototype your app ideas within few minutes. Focus on
>    design itself and no more efforts will be spent on making a component.
> 3. Fast Previewing - Test on actual device instantly Scan the generated QR code to preview prototypes on the actual device
>    instantly, no USB cable or remote publishing required. Carry and share
>    your prototypes offline with teammates or clients in order to gather
>    feedback. The cloud sync makes it faster and easier to preview
>    prototype on mobile device.
> 4. Fast Learn - Code-free and get started right away Just focus on design itself rather than the tool. You can get started easily without
>    the risk of falling into the tool's slave by investing a lot of time
>    and money on learning and training. With Mockplus, you don’t need to
>    worry about programming knowledge any more, let alone coding.
>
> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There's two that come to mind, first, there's Wireframe.cc. There is a free and premium version. The free version appears to meet your requirements of,

- Being free, ya!
- Online based, it's a web app - no software required
- Can share public links
- Appears to be able to be used on tablets with no issues

The premium version just includes private accounts & wireframes, multipaged wireframes, clickable elements, an export feature to PDF & PNG, and allows for revisions. This should work for what you're trying to do.

## [wireframe|cc](http://wireframe.cc) (freemium)

> Wireframe.cc offers a clutter-free environment instead of countless toolbars and icons that we all know from other tools and apps. You can now focus on your ideas and easily sketch them before they fade away.
>
> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Update Nov 2021: [wireframe.cc](https://wireframe.cc/) are no longer "Freemium". They now offer you a free 7-day trial of the full version; and then you *must* switch to a subscription plan (Minimum 16$/month at this time).